# how to fix no matching function ifstream error?

Tags: c++

I'm not sure how to fix the error(below). Can someone help me?

BTW: it runs on VS2012 fine, but when i run on linux terminal it gives me this error

error:

> Librarian.cpp:20: error: no matching function for call to
>   ‘std::basic_ifstream >::basic_ifstream(s 
>   td::string&, const     std::_Ios_Openmode&)’

Librarian.cpp:

```
bool Librarian::addBooks(string file)
{
    ifstream infile(file);
    if (!infile) 
    {
        cerr << "File could not be opened." << endl;
        return false;
    }

    for (;;) {
        char s[MAX];
        infile.getline(s, MAX);
        if (infile.eof()) break;
        cout << s << endl;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: @chris how would i do that?

Comment: Look at the documentation for your compiler's options. Most likely it's just `-std=c++11`.

Comment: @chirs am i doing this right?       -bash-3.2$ g++ -std=c++11  BinaryTree.cpp ChildrenBook.cpp Library.cpp Librarian.cpp main.cpp
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"

Comment: It doesn't have to be that. Try `-std=c++0x`. It should be clear in the documentation for your version of GCC.

Comment: I'm guessing you are missing an include - VC proabably does this for you. Have you #include'd iostream and fstream? Or you might need `using namespace std;`

Comment: @suspectus i included those in the Librarian.cpp file, however it is still not working

Comment: @chris i've just tried the ++0x one and it gave me the same error.

Comment: @suspectus g++ (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)
Copyright (C) 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [std::basic_ifstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream), the constructor does not take `string&` until C++11. Prior to C++11, it only takes `const char *`. Easiest solution to your problem is:

```
 ifstream infile(file.c_str());
```

`std::string::c_str()` gets the underlying char pointer of the string so you can use in the constructor. Or you can use the C++11 as suggested in comments but it depends on your compiler version (looks like your compiler does not support it).